# Exporting a UV in background mode

Tags: python, uv

I am running background mode on a VM without GPU. When I call bpy.ops.uv.export_layout I'm getting an error "GPU functions for drawing are not available in background mode"

I'm just calling:

```
bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath=layoutOut, opacity=1.0)
```

Because of this, I'm stuck at Blender 2.79, when it used to work. Is there some other way to export a UV layout in background?

...OK, it doesn't work on our GPU rendering server either!

Comment: can confirm that svg output works fine in a headless blender, you could then use other utility to convert to png, inkscape or imagemagick can do it from the script or run a batch later

Comment: SVG... yes, of course! It's a vector map after all. I'll give that a try and get back ... before the bounty expires.

Comment: Yup, that'll work. I should be able to write something to parse it; it's just a pile of polygons. Not sure why Blender requires the GPU to do it. Thanks for that; I guess I should wait for any other suggestions, but if you post it as an answer, you're first in line for the bounty.

Comment: no problem, the exporter uses a python gpu module to draw the layout, and I guess that is not available in background mode... but sgv works as it is just text, so if you run 'bpy.ops.uv.export_layout' with mode='SVG' it should export the svg and later you could use for instance 'inkscape --export-filename=layout.png layout.svg' if you need pngs, it can export to pdf too

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to see what happens if you disable GPU in settings in the blend file before submitting it.  Blender should be able to render anything in CPU mode, including UV Maps.  Otherwise, maybe file a bug?

Comment: I found the "Cycles Render Devices" in Preferences - System, but that doesn't appear to save in the blend file. bpy.types.PreferencesSystem doesn't look too helpful either. Yes, it should definitely be able to render in CPU mode, it's doing it on 2.79. Yes, I may yet file a bug. Many thanks for that suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The svg part of the uv layout exporter should work fine in headless mode, as it does not use the gpu module -such module is just a software library that allows to draw to the screen or to a texture-.

The svg output is in vector format but you can run a conversion tool later to get a raster file if needed, inkscape can be that tool. Here a comparison of how it looks, blender png export against svg > inkscape > png, it's pretty much the same...

[image: uv layout image]

and here is blender's [uv export script](https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/tree/master/io_mesh_uv_layout) in case you are curious to check